# Migrating shared project from VS 2013 to 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, csproj, migrating, shared-project

We have a solution on VS 2013 that contains a shared code project type (https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui).

We made some minor changes in this code and it has being part of our solution for a while.

Now I want to open this project in VS 2015. Although I had a minor problem with the shared project that seems to be fixed: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/issues/48

I still cannot get rid of the more than 5000 errors on this project. I can run it successfully, but have no idea the reason for so many errors.

One thing I noticed is VS 2015 uses a standard C# project in the solution explorer instead of a special icon indicating a shared project.

How to reproduce the problem:
1 - Download the Modern UI project from github;
2 - Open it on VS 2015;
3 - Make the fix I mentioned here: https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/issues/48
4 - Reload the shared project after fixing the project file
5 - Notice the number of errors on the error list.

Any ideas?

Igor.

Comment: It seems there is a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565489/why-i-cant-create-shared-project-in-visual-studio-2015.
I cannot create a new shared Project either.

Comment: Can you please add a small screen shot of the error messages?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is related to missing files during VS 2015 setup due to the choices I did during setup.

All I did was creating a new Project and choose Windows 8 template. Then the VS 2015 setup is launch and the missing packages are properly installed.

After doing that, I could open my VS 2013 Project in VS 2015 like a charm.

Igor.