# Visual Studio 2015 and Shared Projects on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, shared-project

When I try to create a Shared Project in Visual Studio 2015 I get the same error dialog as in this post.

[Why can't I create Shared Project in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31565489/97382)

Unfortunately I'm on Windows 7 so I don't get the "Windows 8" project template option which allowed the poster to install the missing templates.

I haven't been able to find a definitive statement regarding the ability to use a Shared Project on Windows 7. Has anyone found a hack to allow creation of Shared Projects on Windows 7?

Comment: I've noticed this as well, and wanted to note that this was available in the RC.

Comment: @Magus, I hadn't thought to check the RC. I've got another machine that still has the RC installed and sure enough I was able to create a Shared Project (on Windows 7) using the RC. IIRC the RC was the Enterprise edition and I'm using Professional of the RTM.

Comment: When I installed Enterprise RTM, it said specifically that it needed to update the currently installed Windows 8/8.1 package, which is probably the cause.

Comment: Looks like a solution was found in the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31672679/1262927