# Unable to open Shared Projects in VS 2015 Community Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've recently taken over maintaining a C# project that includes several .shproj files. I'd not come across these before however a quick search revealed that they're Visual Studio Shared Projects.

However in VS 2015 Community Edition I'm unable to either open or create shared projects, and I'm given an error telling me that the project is incompatible with the current edition of VS.

There seems to be very limited info on shared projects, however what I have found seems to indicate that they should work fine on VS 2015

I've checked the contents of the shproj file and it states the minimum VS version as 14.0, whilst I'm running 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, so that shouldn't be an issue either.

The only other post I could find anywhere regarding vs2015 being unable to open shared projects was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565489/why-cant-i-create-shared-project-in-visual-studio-2015) which is a completely different error.

The error I'm receiving:

[image: VS2015 error]

if anybody knows a potential fix, please let me know. I'd rather not have to restructure this entire project just because I can't open shared project files.

Comment: I suspect you need to install support for Universal Windows and/or Portable Class library when installing Visual Studio 2015. You may need to modify your current install and add it.

Comment: Already tried that, I have every extention I can select installed.